# How to change color of rows if all rows are empty. VBA or not?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I am having a problem changing the color of rows depending on if the cells in that row contain any writing. I am trying to do this formatting in VBA or if there are any suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Color is different between version `Excel 2003`, `Excel 2007`, `Excel 2010` and `Excel 2013` but this remains constant:

```
Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A” & n & “:D” & m).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

3 -> Red

Comment: Is that in the function window or in VBA and I am in 2007. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Going for the "or not" part of the Title and assuming (1) a row extends from ColumnA to ColumnZ inclusive (can be extended) (2) the formatting is to apply when any cell in the row is not populated (can be reversed) and (3) a populated cell may contain either text or number value (can be adjusted) then:

Select ColumnsA:Z, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**

```
=COUNTA($A1:$Z1)=0
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd> and select formatting of choice, OK, OK.